# How to reuse same formulas within a cell in Google Sheets without copy pasting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, reusability, simplify

I am working with a large (but simple) formula In Google Sheets that re-uses the same blocks of formulas repeatedly. To get a bunch of data from a bunch of different tabs I have to use 708 characters in that block of formulas. But then I need to repeatedly reference that data over and over within just the 1 cell which multiplies the length of the formula to the point where I can't even tell what is going on any more.

For example I have a cell with the final code (with 2216 characters) of:

```
=iferror(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("a",concatenate(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Brown!$C$3:$C$68&Brown!$D$3:$D$68,Brown!H$3:H$68,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Godoy!$C$3:$C$76&Godoy!$D$3:$D$76,Godoy!H$3:H$76,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Sindel!$C$7:$C$60&Sindel!$D$7:$D$60,Sindel!H$7:H$60,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Taylor!$C$3:$C$82&Taylor!$D$3:$D$82,Taylor!H$3:H$82,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Wanner!$C$3:$C$55&Wanner!$D$3:$D$55,Wanner!H$3:H$55,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Gehrman!$C$3:$C$16&Gehrman!$D$3:$D$16,Gehrman!H$3:H$16,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Francois!$C$3:$C$17&Francois!$D$3:$D$17,Francois!H$3:H$17,"")))))),"A",average(ArrayFormula(mid(concatenate(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Brown!$C$3:$C$68&Brown!$D$3:$D$68,Brown!H$3:H$68,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Godoy!$C$3:$C$76&Godoy!$D$3:$D$76,Godoy!H$3:H$76,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Sindel!$C$7:$C$60&Sindel!$D$7:$D$60,Sindel!H$7:H$60,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Taylor!$C$3:$C$82&Taylor!$D$3:$D$82,Taylor!H$3:H$82,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Wanner!$C$3:$C$55&Wanner!$D$3:$D$55,Wanner!H$3:H$55,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Gehrman!$C$3:$C$16&Gehrman!$D$3:$D$16,Gehrman!H$3:H$16,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Francois!$C$3:$C$17&Francois!$D$3:$D$17,Francois!H$3:H$17,"")))),sequence(len(concatenate(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Brown!$C$3:$C$68&Brown!$D$3:$D$68,Brown!H$3:H$68,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Godoy!$C$3:$C$76&Godoy!$D$3:$D$76,Godoy!H$3:H$76,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Sindel!$C$7:$C$60&Sindel!$D$7:$D$60,Sindel!H$7:H$60,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Taylor!$C$3:$C$82&Taylor!$D$3:$D$82,Taylor!H$3:H$82,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Wanner!$C$3:$C$55&Wanner!$D$3:$D$55,Wanner!H$3:H$55,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Gehrman!$C$3:$C$16&Gehrman!$D$3:$D$16,Gehrman!H$3:H$16,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Francois!$C$3:$C$17&Francois!$D$3:$D$17,Francois!H$3:H$17,"")))))),1)*1))),"")
```

This looks crazy long, but it is only because I am using this one formula (with 708 characters):

```
concatenate(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Brown!$C$3:$C$68&Brown!$D$3:$D$68,Brown!H$3:H$68,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Godoy!$C$3:$C$76&Godoy!$D$3:$D$76,Godoy!H$3:H$76,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Sindel!$C$7:$C$60&Sindel!$D$7:$D$60,Sindel!H$7:H$60,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Taylor!$C$3:$C$82&Taylor!$D$3:$D$82,Taylor!H$3:H$82,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Wanner!$C$3:$C$55&Wanner!$D$3:$D$55,Wanner!H$3:H$55,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Gehrman!$C$3:$C$16&Gehrman!$D$3:$D$16,Gehrman!H$3:H$16,""))),TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,arrayformula(if($B3&$C3=Francois!$C$3:$C$17&Francois!$D$3:$D$17,Francois!H$3:H$17,""))))
```

3 times within the cell.

Is it possible to have one cell just contain the block of functions that I want to use (as a string) and then somehow convert the string to code to reuse it without making a monster function?

For example, could I assign A1 to hold the long code that I want to have multiple times and then have a formula like:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("a",textToFormula(A1))),"A",AVERAGE(ArrayFormula(mid(textToFormula(A1),sequence(len(textToFormula(A1))),1)*1)).
```

I should also mention that there is no room in my sheet to just put the string of data I am looking for in a separate cell, because I have to apply this formula roughly 50 rows and 180 columns.

Comment: If you're looking for an `eval`, no, there's no such function. Usually ArrayFormula hacks can get you what you want. I can take a look if you want to share a copy of the sheet. Or you can write an apps script that can reduce repetition and call it from your sheet.

Comment: If you provide more details on your current situation, including a copy of your spreadsheet (free of sensitive information), people here could find out whether some formula reworking, or an Apps Script function would be appropriate here.

Comment: The main idea is to search for students by first and last name in each of the teacher tabs. Then the "main" sheet will take the average of all the student scores. If any 1 class puts an "A" for absent, then the "main" tab will put an "A" instead of the average score. Here is an old general version I made a while back: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Al2HxW8viHNZC6KQ7WjKeI_FSR4MxywkgBIQhlxL9Jc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @mrmath3 Is "A" the only non-numerical input allowed?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz That is correct. "A" is the only non-numerical input.

Answer (score 2):

Ouch! That is a long formula! Sadly, there's no `eval()` like in JavaScript, but we can at least make you a simpler formula.

How about this one? It's still a bit long, but far less complex. It only Queries each sheet once. This one works in cell F3, but can be dragged.

```
=IF(
  JOIN("",{Teacher1!G$7:G;Teacher2!G$7:G;Teacher3!G$7:G;Teacher4!G$7:G;Teacher5!G$7:G})<>"",
  IFERROR(Average(ArrayFormula(--{
    QUERY(ArrayFormula(TO_TEXT(Teacher1!$A$7:$GX)),"select Col"&COLUMN()+1&" where Col3='"&$B3&"' and Col4='"&$C3&"'");
    QUERY(ArrayFormula(TO_TEXT(Teacher2!$A$7:$GX)),"select Col"&COLUMN()+1&" where Col3='"&$B3&"' and Col4='"&$C3&"'");
    QUERY(ArrayFormula(TO_TEXT(Teacher3!$A$7:$GX)),"select Col"&COLUMN()+1&" where Col3='"&$B3&"' and Col4='"&$C3&"'");
    QUERY(ArrayFormula(TO_TEXT(Teacher4!$A$7:$GX)),"select Col"&COLUMN()+1&" where Col3='"&$B3&"' and Col4='"&$C3&"'");
    QUERY(ArrayFormula(TO_TEXT(Teacher5!$A$7:$GX)),"select Col"&COLUMN()+1&" where Col3='"&$B3&"' and Col4='"&$C3&"'")}
  )),"A"),
  ""
)
```

The Query Statement:

- Each cell queries each sheet as a table where the name is matched in the sheet as a row.
- The `COLUMN()+1` is to get the corresponding columns to line up. I.e. If we're in column F (6), we want to look in column G (7).
- The `TO_TEXT` allows us to look for non-numbers (`"A"`).

After that, convert each query result to a number with `--`, then take the `Average`. If any of the numbers cannot be converted to a number, `Average` gives us an error, and we assume the value was `"A"`.

In the case that all cells in a column for a date are blank (the blank `JOIN`), bypass the queries altogether and output a blank cell.

Comment: That formula is beautiful!

Comment: The problem with putting this formula in all of the cells is that for each individual cell in the "Main" tab when the average is 0 (i.e. we haven't gotten to that date yet and is blank), then the "Main" tab isn't blank - but is the numerical value of 0. This affects the average score in column E. The only way I know how to make that value blank instead of 0 is by doing a IF() command...which would duplicate the length of the code by 2. Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: @mrmath3 That does make things tricky. I think I came up with a clever solution for that. It's slightly shorter than doubling the length of the code. You may also consider using named ranges as well to tidy things up. Check the edited answer.